# how can i get end user api key for bigquery usage

Tags: google-bigquery

If I have to build an android app on top of big query apis then I want the end users to supply their own api key as they will be billed on their usage .How can I achieve this ? Is it ok to ask the user for the api key in settings and store it on client side ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific end user API key.  All API keys are obtained from the APIs Console at https://code.google.com/apis/console/  It is okay to ask end users to supply their own key as long as you understand the interface is really designed for developers. You'll probably want to supply step-by-step instructions specific to your application.

Out of curiosity - what is the app you're building?

Comment: Thanx a lot for the reply .I'm trying to explore if i can build a nice app on mobile/tablet and abstract the query formation part from the end user .

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery bills users based on their usage (data storage and data analysis), but it does not charge for API calls made by applications.  So it should be fine for you to use your own API key for all users.

Your app will most likely need to ask users which project they'd like to use to store data and/or run jobs.  That project ID will be used to bill the user for their usage, so as long as that project ID is owned by the user, you should be fine.  (By the way, the bigquery.projects.list method can be used to retrieve a list of projects available to the user so that you can help them choose which one to use with BigQuery.  If they don't have any projects yet, they'll need to create one at http://code.google.com/apis/console.)

Comment: As per my understanding the big query billing depends on two factors storage and queries . https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/pricing                             The storage will be taken care by the project ,but the queries are tracked against the API key as per this link  https://developers.google.com/console/help/#UsingKeys                               Do let me know if my undestanding is wrong.